# SELECT and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-8.3

I just want to filter few columns from the table according to `MAX(ts)`. `ts = timestamp`. And everything is OK if I select only two columns - deviceid and ts:

```
SELECT deviceid, MAX(ts) 
FROM device_data 
GROUP BY deviceid
```

and the result:

[image]

but I also need two columns more - longitude and lattitude. I have the problem if I select longitude and lattitude because they have to appear in GROUP BY and I get too much results with the same deviceid:

[image]

How can I avoid inserting longitude and lattitude in GROUP BY?

Comment: What is the DBMS you are using?

Comment: Which database? Im thinking u need nested queries but the syntax may vary dependent on database used.

Comment: Sorry for none of information about DBMS. I am using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions for this. One is to use window functions to get the first longitude, latitude, ...etc within a partition of same deviceid when ordered by descending date.

Then you will get duplicates, which you can remove with `distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT deviceid, 
       FIRST_VALUE(longitude) OVER win AS longitude,
       FIRST_VALUE(latitude) OVER win AS latitute,
       FIRST_VALUE(ts) OVER win AS ts 
FROM   device_data
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY deviceid ORDER BY ts DESC);
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to run above SELECT DISTINCT but I am getting an error at first OVER: syntax error at or near OVER

Comment: Which version of postgresql are you running on?

Comment: @DamianKowalewski: if you get an error with that query you are either not using Postgres or using a **very**, **very** old version (and unsupported) of Postgres

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.3.23. I have tried solution sent by @penguin and it works. :)

Comment: @DamianKowalewski You should upgrade your Postgres version now. 8.3 has been [out of support](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) for nearly 5 years now

Comment: @trincot your solutions works on postgresql 10 also :) thank you

Comment: Yes, you should really move away from 8.x. You're welcome ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table that contains `device_id` and max of `ts` per `device_id`, then do an inner join with original `device_data` to get desired result.

Unless you have multiple rows with same `device_id` and `max(ts)`, this should work.

```
SELECT a.deviceid, a.ts, a.longitude, a.lattitude
FROM device_data a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT deviceid, MAX(ts) as max_ts
FROM device_data 
GROUP BY deviceid) b ON a.ts = b.max_ts
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;
```

Comment: I will create another one ask so you can help me also in other subject of sql :)